# React navigation issue when setting default route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to build a navigation where I have a problem when I add

```
{
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
 }
```

When I use the stacknavigator without initialRouteName everything works fine. I am working on ios simulation (react-native run-ios) and I tried pod install already a few times.

**This is app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Loading from './Loading';
import SignUp from './SignUp';
import Login from './Login';
import Main from './Main';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
 { 
   Home: Loading,
   Home: SignUp,
   Home: Login,
   Home: Main,
 },
 {
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
 }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**This is the error:**

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'routeConfigs[initialRouteName].params')

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

getInitialState
    StackRouter.js:1:2241
getStateForAction
    StackRouter.js:1:4880
NavigationContainer
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:99867:102
renderRoot
    [native code]:0
runRootCallback
    [native code]:0
unstable_runWithPriority
    scheduler.development.js:643:23
failedRoots.forEach$argument_0
    react-refresh-runtime.development.js:201:29
forEach
    [native code]:0
failedRoots.forEach$argument_0
    react-refresh-runtime.development.js:193:24
Refresh.performReactRefresh
    setUpReactRefresh.js:43:6
setTimeout$argument_0
    require.js:609:10
_callTimer
    JSTimers.js:146:14
callTimers
    JSTimers.js:399:17
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "kowop",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.32",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem may be?

Thanks a lot!

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, initialroutename is using by indexed name, not screen name. In your project, you have to use 'Home'.

So you have to use different name between screens. like,

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
 { 
   loading: Loading,
   signUp: SignUp,
   login: Login,
   main: Main,
 },
 {
  initialRouteName: 'loading',
 }
);
```

Aside, I think use name 'Home' for four screen is very bad idea. You have to try use different name between screens.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
 {
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
 }
```

To :

```
 {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
 }
```

Screen key should be passed to `initialRouteName` as param

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was indeed not referring to the screen.